# Is there a way to get the last n lines of screen output programmatically?

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm working with a detached `screen` session, and I'd like to be able to check what the last lines of output on the screen session are (for example, to determine if a password prompt is being displayed). I can obviously do this by examining the contents of the log file created with `-L`, but I'm hoping there is a command to grab the visible contents of the screen buffer in some way that can be manipulated programmatically. I've looked at the `screen` commands list and it's not immediately clear whether any of them can be used to accomplish this. I'm using `Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06`, if that's relevant.